How to transform pandas dataframe - column headers and rows
This is my original dataframe:



A
B
C
D
E
Year 2020_AA
Year 2020_AB
Year 2021_AA
Year 2021_AB




abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
0
0
0
0



I want to transform the dataframe into:



A
B
C
D
E
Year
AA
AB




abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
2020
0
0


abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
2021
0
0



I tried using following lines of code - df.melt converts the data into a below structure but pivot_table does not work and shows empty dataframe:
# Melt the DataFrame
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], var_name='Type', value_name='Value')

# Split the 'Type' column into 'Delivery Year' and 'Type'
df_melt[['Delivery Year', 'Type']] = df_melt['Type'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

# Pivot the DataFrame
pivot_df = df_melt.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Delivery Year'], columns='Type', values='Value', fill_value=0).reset_index()




A
B
C
D
E
Type
Value
Delivery Year




abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
AA
0
Year 2020


abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
AB
0
Year 2020


abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
AA
0
Year 2021


abc
abc
NaN
NaN
abc
AB
0
Year 2021



To recreate my dataframe, use the below code:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': 'abc',
    'B': 'abc',
    'C': np.NaN,
    'D': np.NaN,
    'E': 'abc',
    'Year 2020_AA': [0],
    'Year 2020_AB': [0],
    'Year 2021_AA': [0],
    'Year 2021_AB': [0]
})


Any guidance is most appreciated.

Code
out = (df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
         .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(
             x.columns.str.split(' ').str[1].str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)
              )
         .stack(0).reset_index().rename({'level_5': 'Year'}, axis=1)
)

out:


To make the above code more understandable, it would look like this
tmp = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
idx = tmp.columns.str.split(' ').str[1].str.split('_', expand=True)
idx.names = ['Year',None]
out = tmp.set_axis(idx, axis=1).stack(0,future_stack=True).reset_index()

same result
